# Uninitialized pointers vs NULL and 0

Tags: c, pointers, initialization

I have a uninitialized int pointer. And when printed this always shows as 0.

But when checked against NULL it does not pass the condition.

And interestingly this wild pointer takes value without throwing Segmentation Fault.

Any explanations??

Code below:

```
int main (){

int *p1;
int *p2;
int var=90;
printf("p1 = %x\n", p1);
printf("p2 = %x\n", p2);

p1 = &var;

if(p2==NULL)
{return 0;}

*p2 = *p1;

printf("*p2 = %x\n", *p2);

}
```

Output looks like this..

```
# gcc -std=c99 -o main *.c
# main
p1 = 0
p2 = 0
*p2 = 90
```

Comment: Why don't you fix your program by initializing the pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note: You need to `#include <stdio.h>` to compile your code.)

This is one possible explanation:

The value of `p2` is *indeterminate*. Using an indeterminate value causes *undefined behaviour*, even if it is just a `NULL` check. From this point on, there is no particular behaviour required of the comparison operator, or any other part of the code either for that matter.

As a result, the indeterminate value of `p2` doesn't have to compare equal to `NULL`, even if it turns out that `p2` actually *is* `NULL` when you print it out. The compiler is free to simply remove the test from the compiled code.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.. I'm able to appreciate compiler's design. Could anyone suggest a book on c compiler optimization techniques for me to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 5):

Several points:

1. Use `%p` to print `void *` pointers.
2. The internal value of a null pointer isn't necessarily `0`, although it usually is in modern machines.
3. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior, anything could happen. In particular, it doesn't mean segmentation fault will always happen.

To sum up, exploring UB like this doesn't prove anything.